# Help on determining the effect of a drug in tumor counts in a within subject design

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures, count-data, poisson-regression

Thank you all in advance,

I am having difficulties in deciding the best way to determine the effect of a treatment from observational data (there are no RCTs available).
I have an observational cohort of transplanted patients that are at high risk of developing multiple skin tumors (events) following transplantation.
Empirically when they start to develop several tumors or one aggressive tumor their immunosuppressive treatment is changed to include a particular drug of interest which might be useful in lowering the risk of future events.

OBJECTIVE:
I want to compare the counts/rates of events, with each patient being its own control (within subject/repeated measures),  from the time they  were under the standard treatment with the time they are under this new drug. As you can see from the figure, the length of this two periods varies greatly between patients.[image]

My thoughts:
I first started looking at survival models such as a Cox regression with mixed effects or recurrent events models, but I now believe that a GLM with mixed-effects based on a Poisson or quassiPoisson model may be better suited to my data (feel free to suggest other approaches).

Regarding the use of a Poisson model I am not sure whether to include an exposure variable such as days under each treatment as an offset or as a predictor variable to account for the different length of exposure to each regime. I also included an interaction term for `time_exposed` and `treatment`.
Considering the `lme4` R package syntax this is what I have so far: `glmer( Tumor_count ~ treatment + time_exposed + time_exposed:treatment + (1| Patient_ID) + other_covs, family= “poisson”, data= df)`

Some considerations:

- The start of this drug is usually indicated due to a recent event.
- Having one event is heavily correlated with having recurrent events.
- The more time people spend with regular immunosuppressive therapy the more skin cancer risk they seem to have in the future (e.g.  permanent DNA damage) .
- The more time passes since the time of transplant the higher the risk of developing an event (i.e. age, immunosuppressive medication, UV exposure keep adding risk to the subject as time goes by), I think this can be accounted for by adding both Age and time_since_transplant as covariates.

Thank you very much any suggestions will be of great help.

Comment: After some research I believe a Prentice, Williams and Peterson (PWP) Conditional
Model will be the most appropriate model for this data. https://www.omicsonline.org/open-access/an-overview-of-statistical-models-for-recurrent-events-analysis-a-review.pdf